# Foreach loop uses more stack memory than traditional for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, memory, stack

In one of my programs I was using a for each loop that looked similar to this

```
for(auto component : components) {
    doSomethingWithComponent(component);
}
```

and visual studio complained that this would cause the function to use more stack memory than the maximum, so I changed the loop to:

```
for(int i = 0;i<components.size();i++) {
    doSomethingWithComponent(components[i]);
}
```

and the warning went away.  Is this because a for each loop generates a reference/copy of the current iteration of object in the loop? But if that is the case, I don't think that a single struct with a few integers would consume that much memory?  Is there a reason for this to occur?

EDIT:
`components` is an `std::vector` if that changes anything

Comment: Range-based for loop is just a wrapper for regular for loop. Possible reason might be that `auto component` performs a copy of whatever component is. You should use `auto const &` or `auto &` if you don't need copies.

Comment: What's the type of `compnent`/`compnents[i]`? Does this change when making the loop variable a reference, `for (aoto& component : components)`?

Comment: Using `auto& const` made it no longer show the warning, so was this happening by copying the component instead of refrencing it?  But what happens to the copies on each iteration? are they replaced, destroyed, or held onto until the loop finishes>

Comment: @Genjutsu This entirely depends on the type of `components`; if it's a `std::vector` and have turned on optimization, you'll probable end up with the same, but in general the non-range-based for loop equivalent would be `for (auto iterator = std::begin(components); iterator != std::end(components); ++iterator) { auto compent = *iterator; doSomethingWithComponent(component); }`

Comment: `components` is a `std::vector`, Ill edit my question

Comment: Yes by not looping over references you will create copies, also check constness requirements and use const auto& if you can. And be sure to evaluate behavior in release builds only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(auto component : components) {
```

This is equivalent to having

```
auto component=components[i];
```

being performed on each iteration of the loop. A (mostly useless) copy is made of each value in the container, on each iteration of the loop. Hence the stack usage.

This is avoided simply by using a reference:

```
for(auto &component : components) {
```

Even better, if the loop is not supposed to modify the contents of the container:

```
for(const auto &component : components) {
```

And your C++ compiler will helpfully complain if, due to a bug, the loop attempts to modify the value in the container.

Comment: One more question, is each copy held until the loops finishes? or is the memory of the copy simply replaced by a new copy each iteration?

Comment: If you add `auto component=components[i]` to your manual `for` loop, the end result will be logically equivalent.